# How to solve the expectation of continuous random variable

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

I encountered some problem while getting the 
$\mathbb{E}[x]$ of a continuous random variable.
The following equation is the PDF that im trying the expectation.

$\mathbb{E}[x] = \int_0^\infty x^2\alpha^2e^{-\alpha x}dx$

I got stuck of how to get next step of
$[-\alpha x^2e^{-\alpha x}]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty 2x \alpha e^{-\alpha x} dx $

Can someone explain to me how to get to this step as I have tried many combination of integration by parts (such as $u=x^2, u=x, v=\int x e^{-\alpha x} dx$  but I just couldnt get to the step above :(

Comment: What about [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)? If this is homework, you should add the "self-study" tag.

Comment: Hint: $u=ax^2, v = -e^{-ax}, dv = ae^{-ax}$, $\int u\, dv = \cdots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could integrate, substitute, and recognize a gamma function, but there is a nicer way to do it: recognize the pdf of a Gamma distribution.

The pdf of a Gamma distribution is
$$
f(x) = \frac{\alpha^\beta}{\Gamma(\beta)} x^{\beta-1} e^{-\alpha x}, \qquad x \ge 0,
$$
and its expectation is $\beta/\alpha$. So, in your case, we have a Gamma(2,$\alpha$), and so its expectation is $2/\alpha$.

If you really want to do the integral:
$$
E(X) = \alpha^2 \int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-\alpha x} d x,
$$
the change of variables $u = \alpha x$ helps:
$$
E(X) = \alpha^2 \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{u}{\alpha} \right)^2 e^{-u} \frac{du}{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^\infty u^{3-1} e^{-u} d u = \frac{\Gamma(3)}{\alpha} = \frac{2}{\alpha}.
$$